# Connect to a PNG image in dashboard and automate the process

Tags: image, png, tableau-api, dashboard

I have a requirement to automate a tableau report which would connect to the image placed in a some common path/URL.

I tried the 'WebPage' option. It works good. but my problem is since the PNG file gets updated everyday with new image , the tableau report would also update with the current image.

I am not sure on how to access the historical data/image in tableau.

Is there anyway to automate in such a way that the historical data(yesterday's PNG iamge) can be accessed also when needed.

PS:I send the tableau package after refreshing the image to BAs on daily basis so that they can update some data in the tableau report.

These PNG images are screenshot of some ppts.

Comment: which option worked for you `Image` or `Web Page` and who are updating the image everyday? If you don't need to get the updated image then can we assume your image as static?

Comment: Your question bit confusing because if you need to see the historic image then you need to have the previous image stored in the same location, If you are updating the image then it is not possible, So it depends on how you design your data

Comment: yes to view the history data the image has to renamed and the tableau file has to be updated with history image URL..  My tableau has lot of PNG images and manually updating the URL each time for viewing history is a time consuming process.  So i would like to know if there are any other options where tableau can connect to image and viewing history is also feasible.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by creating a date parameter and using it in the URL of 'Web Page' to fetch history images

Comment: that great.. can you post this as your answer with detailed steps and then please accept it as the answer... so that the thread is closed and others can use the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the following steps.

```
   1.Created folder in shared path with folder names as dates and placed the 
    images under the folder for respective dates.
   2.Created a date parameter and used it as filter in tableau.
   3.Use the date parameter in the URL
```

By this, when i change the date filter in tableau then images will get updated with picture available under that date folder path.

```
PS. Image names has to be consistent . Only the folder name should change to 
    the date value for everyday.
```